# Intersection between a known object and an index signature

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type that's an intersection of both a known object and an index signature?

In the code below the type should be something like:
`{ a: string, [prop: string]: number }`, such that `a` must always be a `string`, but any other properties must be of type `number`

```js
type Foo<T> = T & Exclude<{ [prop: string]: number }, keyof T>
type Bar = { a: string }
type FooBar = Foo<Bar>

const fooBar1: FooBar = { a: 'hello', b: 1 } // should pass
const fooBar2: FooBar = { a: 'hello', b: 1, c: 'a' } // should fail
const fooBar3: FooBar = { a: 1, b: 1 } // should fail
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxWVAZFAUQA8BjAGwFcATCRAbygG0wAnOMALigGdgWBLAHYBzALpdBFALYAjCCygBfADRQA1hBBwAZtlQAoUJCgAhAIYKsDM114CRSw+Gjw45y7ASJ3B-STiCvFDaCO4AjFyu7phQ1lwA5AAWEGRkcPGqMlxhSlAA9Hk8iXAUZFRQYGbc3H4BQSFuFgBMkaEWMXFQSSlpGVBZUGGqJAlm8bkFRSVlwWb8ZLWBwMFtLADMrY0enUP92ROF3MWl5dpzZEA)

Comment: You can create that type of course but it doesn't do what you want.  No specific type in TypeScript works that way, unfortunately.  See the open issue at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) and the answer to the linked question.